# Can I use/adapt the Kohana userguide module to create help pages for my application?

Tags: module, kohana, user-guide

I'd like to create a userguide for the application I'm building using the Kohana framework, and I'm wondering if there's a way I can use the Kohana userguide module for this purpose.

I understand how to add userguide info for new modules that I create, and how to include my classes in the API, but I want to build a second, separate userguide for the actual application user, as opposed to the app developers.

At first, I thought I'd just try adding app help pages to the main userguide at APPPATH/guide.  I tried adding a "application/guide" directory, and put a file in there called menu.md, but that just ended up replacing the Kohana menu in the userguide.  After renaming the file to menu.myapp.md, it doesn't show up at all.

So then it occurs to me that I could simple edit modules/userguide/guide/menu.md to add sections for my app, and likewise add markdown files for each app component.  But really it would be much better to have a completely separate userguide for app users since the Kohana documentation isn't relevant for them.

What's the best way to go about this?  Should I create a duplicate of the entire userguide module and modify the routing, &c.?  Or is there some way to set up both userguides using the one version of the module?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?  Is there some other module/approach that would be better for building "Help" pages for the app?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make docs for your application with the userguide. If you want examples, check out these links:

- https://github.com/zombor/Auto-Modeler/blob/master/config/userguide.php
- https://github.com/zombor/Auto-Modeler/tree/master/guide/auto-modeler

Note that you'll still get "api docs" and everything else, unless you change the config to hide them.

Comment: I understand the model for adding modules to the userguide, but was hoping for an alternative.  Your answer suggest that the only solution is to create a new "help" module.  Is there no way to build a completely separate user guide, preferably located w/in the application folder?

Comment: There's no difference between files in application/ and files under a module. They are all combined in the filesystem on runtime. Like I said, you'll have to change the config to turn off the links to all the kohana help files.

Comment: Yes, but the point is: what if I want both?  Like I said above, I don't want to get rid of the kohana userguide files and api browser because those are helpful for the app developers.